# Extending view Entities in Apache OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

Is it possible to extend view entities in ofbiz? Especially in a separate entitymodel file as I am trying to isolate my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to do so and i do not think it should be. Views in ofbiz are just an easy way to create queries, so you should just create one when you need it.